# How to get a custom "flair"?

Tags: discussion, flair

I can easily get a left aligned "flair" from my SX profile page under "flair" menu. Like this:

[image]

Questions:

1. How can I get a right aligned one like the following?
2. How to change its background?

[image]

---

**Edit:** Now I know that, from @MartijnPieters's answer, individual SX sites offer several options to choose. Updated questions are:

1. Can we further custom it besides default several ones?
2. How about the network flair?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Stack Exchange flairs come with multiple pre-set background colour themes.

Mysticial didn't customize the flair, but simply picked one of 4 options:

- Default:
  [image]
- Clean:
  [image]
- Dark:
  [image]
- Hot dog stand:
  [image]

The image urls only differ in the `?theme=` parameter, options `clean`, `dark` and `hotdog`.

See the `flair` link in your Stack Overflow profile.

For the network-wide flair the same options exist, but are not documented. Add the `?theme=` parameter manually:

- Default:
  [image]
- Clean (add `?theme=clean`):
  [image]
- Dark (add `?theme=dark`):
  [image]
- Hot dog stand (add `?theme=hotdog`):
  [image]

Comment: Actually, the network flair supports theme options too. It's just undocumented.

Comment: @michaelb958: cool, we'll document that now then!

Comment: Can we further custom it besides default several ones?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: no, these are your options.

Comment: What about adding `?theme=blink` for that '90s look?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: I'll personally come hunt you down with my nunchucks if that ever got implemented. *I hold you responsible!!!1!11eleven!*....

Comment: lol. Tempted to delete my comment now. I don't want to live in fear that one of the SE devs ever gets bored / has some free time and sees my comment.